# How to use ChartDirector.XYChart addLineLayer() method with argument as Double;

Tags: java, double, linkedhashmap, chart-director

I want to display my output in graphical format using ChartDirector.XYChart.When I use its addLineLayer()method with arugument as Double Type array, then it shows an error "The method addLineLayer(double[]) in the type XYChart is not applicable for the arguments (Double[])".but When I use double as argument then it takes the value.The values in Double Array holds the LinkedHashMap value. So it cant't be represented in primitive type double array.
My code is:

```
            //Assign linkedHashMap values to array  
Double[] avg=  (Double[]) averageMap.values().toArray();
char[] time= rs.getString(logtime).toCharArray();
XYChart c = new XYChart(250, 250);
c.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200);
c.addLineLayer(avg);
```

Error is on c.addlineLayer.How to fix it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's worth mentioning that `Double[]` and `double[]` are different types, so you cannot pass one in place of another.  (Just as you can't call a method that expects `int` by passing a `String`).

So you will need to convert your array of Double objects into an array of primitives.  If you have no null values, this is simple:

```
double[] avgsPrim = new double[avg.length];
for (int i = 0; i < avg.length; i++) {
   avgsPrim[i] = avg[i].doubleValue();
}
```

If any of your values *are* null, you'll have to think about what this means in this context, and how you can handle that.  (Skip it?  Substitute it with `Double.NaN`?  Throw an `IllegalArgumentException`?)